# Forms alerts with Vue and sweetalert not registering vue store?

Tags: vue.js, sweetalert

I have a simple login form with a button that has a reactive text `{{ msg }}` by default it says `log in` and when the user sends the form it changes to `logging...`. If the form fails then I want to say `send again`.

I'm using sweetalert for the warnings and I intend to change the `msg` data inside the sweetAlert. However for some reason it returns a `undefined` to `this.msg`

html

```html
<form id="login_form">
 <input class="form-control" type="text" required="" name="email" placeholder="Email">
 <input class="form-control" type="password" required="" name="password" placeholder="Password">
 <button class="btn" type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```js
export default {
 data() {
   return {
     msg: "Log in"
    }
  },
methods: {
submitForm() {
  const loginData = $("#login_form").serializeArray();
  const v = this;
  this.msg = "logging..."
  $.ajax({
    url: "/authentication",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
      strategy: "local",
      email: loginData[0].value,
      password: loginData[1].value
    }),
    success: function (data) {
      window.location.replace("/");
       this.msg = "logged!"
    },
    error: function (error) {
      if (error.status === 401) {
        swal("Wrong email or password");
        this.msg = "Try again?";
        console.log("this.msg) //returns undefined
      } else if (error.status === 400) {
        swal("Wrong email or password");
        this.msg = "Try again?";
      } else {
        swal("Error. Try again!");
        this.msg = "Try again?";
      }
    }
  });
}
}
```

I also tried promises but it also returns `this.msg` as undefined.

if I `console.log(this.msg)` inside the sweetAlert it returns undefined.

Comment: Use arrow functions, ie `success: data => { ... }` instead. Same goes for `error`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: For what does your `const v = this` using for?

Comment: Nothing it seems. May be residual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt its the context behavior. Try this one

```
export default {
 data() {
   return {
     msg: "Log in"
    }
  },
methods: {
submitForm() {
  const self = this;
  const loginData = $("#login_form").serializeArray();
  const v = this;

  self.msg = "logging..."
  $.ajax({
    url: "/authentication",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
      strategy: "local",
      email: loginData[0].value,
      password: loginData[1].value
    }),
    success: function (data) {
      window.location.replace("/");
       self.msg = "logged!"
    },
    error: function (error) {
      if (error.status === 401) {
        swal("Wrong email or password");
        self.msg = "Try again?";
        console.log(self.msg) //returns undefined
      } else if (error.status === 400) {
        swal("Wrong email or password");
        self.msg = "Try again?";
      } else {
        swal("Error. Try again!");
        self.msg = "Try again?";
      }
    }
  });
}
}
```

Comment: adding `this` as a constant did the trick. Thank you i'll make sure I check more in depth the code with my coworkers next time.

Comment: No problem, kindly please accept my answer later if its available thanks.